# Dynamic class based on prop sometimes not applying correctly in Safari

Tags: reactjs, safari

****EDIT:**
Turns out adding class w-full to the first element that has class of relative solves this problem, how and why ? I have no idea, but thanks for wasting my time safari.**

I've searched all over the internet and asked plenty of AIs but the answer is the same either "none" or "use a key on the image to force a re-render", but I don't like that solution and I want to know if there is any better one out there.

The issue is that when changing planets everything looks fine for a moment but then at random times the dynamic classes based on planet stop being applied and looks like the styles are coming from the previous planet, when I check inside the inspector the class is correct and the styles too but it is not rendered correctly until the component is re-rendered even opening inspector in safari causes the image to now has correct styles applied. This issue is really weird and adding a key eliminates this issue.

Basically this problem only rises when using the app on Safari. I have a dynamic class that is based on planetName prop, so when the planetName changes the class is now refering to a different class inside index.css which looks like this:

```
.mercury {
    @apply w-[6.9375rem] md:w-[11.5rem] lg:w-auto;
}

.venus {
    @apply w-[9.625rem] md:w-[15.8125rem] lg:w-auto;
}

.earth {
    @apply w-[10.8125rem] md:w-[17.8125rem] lg:w-auto;
}

.mars {
    @apply w-[8.0625rem] md:w-[13.3125rem] lg:w-auto;
}

.jupiter {
    @apply w-[14rem] md:w-[23.0625rem] lg:w-auto;
}

.saturn {
    @apply w-[16rem] md:w-[26.375rem] lg:w-auto;
}

.uranus {
    @apply w-[11rem] md:w-[18.125rem] lg:w-auto;
}

.neptune {
    @apply w-[10.8125rem] md:w-[17.8125rem] lg:w-auto;
}
```

This is needed because each of the image has different size on different screen sizes.

This is my PlanetImage component:

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import Spinner from '@components/Spinner.tsx';
import getPlanetColor from '@utils/getPlanetColor.ts';
import { fadeIn, rotateInfinite } from '@/animations';
import lowercase from '@utils/lowercase.ts';

type PlanetImageProps = {
  planetName: string;
  src: string;
  geologyImageSrc: string;
  showGeologyImage: boolean;
};

const PlanetImage = ({
  planetName,
  src,
  geologyImageSrc,
  showGeologyImage,
}: PlanetImageProps) => {
  const [planetImageLoading, setPlanetImageLoading] = useState(true);
  const planetImageRef = useRef<HTMLImageElement | null>(null);
  const planetImageWrapperRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const geologyImageRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const planetImage = planetImageRef.current;
    if (planetImage && !planetImage.complete) {
      setPlanetImageLoading(true);
    }
  }, [src]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (showGeologyImage) {
      fadeIn({
        element: geologyImageRef,
      });
    }
  }, [showGeologyImage]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const planetImageWrapper = planetImageWrapperRef.current;
    if (planetImageWrapper) {
      rotateInfinite({
        element: planetImageWrapperRef,
        duration: 60,
      });
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="relative select-none pointer-events-none">
      {planetImageLoading && <Spinner fillColor={getPlanetColor(planetName)} />}
      <div className={planetImageLoading ? 'hidden' : 'block'}>
        <div ref={planetImageWrapperRef}>
          <img
            ref={planetImageRef}
            className={`block object-contain h-auto max-w-full mx-auto ${lowercase(
              planetName
            )}`}
            src={src}
            onLoad={() => setPlanetImageLoading(false)}
            alt={planetName}
          />
        </div>
        <div
          ref={geologyImageRef}
          className={`${
            showGeologyImage ? 'block' : 'hidden'
          } absolute left-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 top-[63%] opacity-0`}
        >
          <img
            className="object-contain h-auto max-w-[4.2rem] md:max-w-[6.8rem] lg:max-w-[10.1875rem]"
            src={geologyImageSrc}
            alt="Planet geology"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PlanetImage;
```

When I add `key={planetName}` to the `img` everything renders fine at all times, but as i've said this is not a solution I prefer since key is used to differentiate item in a list and this feels hacky.